# PHP: Returning a user to their original page after login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, user-experience, http-referer

Are there any 'best practices' concerning how one should return a user to their original page after logging in to your website, specifically in PHP? e.g. if I'm viewing a StackOverflow question while not logged in, how would you ensure that I return to this question if I logged in?

From my research, it seems a lot of advice centers around the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable. Basically, you take note of the referer and store it in the session, then redirect back to that page when you're done.

The problem with this is that HTTP_REFERER is unreliable at best.

> This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.
>   — [http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php]

Any edits to the referer to redirect to other areas of the site will be handled by routine permissions checks. If the referer gets blanked out, it might be acceptable to simply redirect the user to the main page of the site rather than the page they came from. This seems needlessly user hostile though, and I was hoping there would be some better way to handle this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On login page:

```
<form action="controller/LoginController" method="post">
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="l" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']).'" />';
}

?>
<!-- the rest of the form -->
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

At login controller, you take in the `$_POST['l']` value and see whether or not this URL is on your own website. If it isn't, redirect to your default page, else redirect to this URL.

Make sure that on your login page if user is already logged in, you redirect the user back to home page or something. This will prevent cases like redirecting back to login.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is a browser responsibility. It is also most of the time rather reliable. If the browser doesn't send, or if you are worried about it, you can use session instead.

on every page simply set `$_SESSION['lastvisitpage']` to the current page URL. On login then you redirect to `$_SESSION['lastvisitpage']`.

Since `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be faked by a user at any time, one should always treat is any other user-supplied variable by properly escaping it.

Comment: So HTTP_REFERER *is* the standard way to do this then? I like the idea of using a 'lastpage' session variable as a backup for the case of a blank referer. Thanks!

Comment: no problem at all. But be wary of the SESSION method because you never know if the user opened multiple tabs of your site in his/her browser. If this answers put a tick to it allowing others to know =)

Comment: Good point (multiple tabs). This seems like it works best with multiple fallbacks. If there's a hidden form element, use it. If not, check the HTTP_REFERER on the login page and use that. If that's blank too, either use whatever the session says the last page was, or throw the user back to the main page. It might come down to a matter of opinion on which of those two options provides the better user experience. 'Main Page' is likely less confusing than being pushed to a page you have open in another tab, but it's a worse experience in cases of single tabs where the 'Last Page' is reliable.

Comment: You should consider `$_SERVER` tainted. At least apply `htmlspecialchars` to it before inserting it straight into HTML.

Comment: @Geert - Absolutely. It's sort of implied by the quote I included: "In short, it cannot really be trusted." WebDev 101 says you always need to sanitize your inputs. I'd probably end up throwing it through the sanitizer script I found, and then running a couple quick sanity checks on it to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you store the last visited page on your own, maybe with the help of a session.

If the user requests a page from your website the first time, start a new session and initialize *last-URI* with the current URI. Update this *last-URI* whenever another page is requested until it’s the login page. Now if the authentication is successful, you can redirect to user to the URI in *last-URI*.

And if you have a login form on every page, use a hidden input where the current URI is stored in.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(user_not_logged_in())
{
    $link = "http://example.com/login?continue=path/to/current/page";
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Loign</a>';
}
```

This is how I, and sites like Google, does it. You would need to make sure that you check the continue variable and sanitize it of weird URLs first however.

Another option is use AJAX, and allow the user to login from any page. User logs in, you submit the form via AJAX, refresh when the request comes back.

---

I think you might be asking if the user specifically clicks on the login link on a menu, you automatically think that the user wants to be redirected to the page that they pressed the button from. This I believe is a flaw in logic. Take StackOverflow. Just because I press login doesn't mean I want to return to the question I was last on.

However, there are some instances that it would be correct to assume the person wants to go back, such as if I upvoted a question and got the popup telling me to login. If I clicked the link there, it would be safe to assume that I want to go back. But just the login link on the nav bar doesn't have that implied meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make an AJAX call to login the user and on successful AJAX response just refresh the current page.

Comment: you cannot make such an important feature to be Javascript-dependent unless you are able to have a Javascript-fail safe back up for this.

Comment: I'd pretty much echo what @thephpdeveloper said. I'd really like everything to work well when javascript isn't available.

Comment: I prefer the AJAX call, but I also have a standard login page if Javascript doesn't load. The page however does redirect to the main page. No Javascript = No Saving Your Location.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP sessions and the $_SESSION object to define a "continue location". Here is the code I use in one of my projects. When the user is logged in, I set the $_SESSION['loggedin'] to TRUE.

Here is the code to check on a sub-page, let's call it "sub-page.php" if the user is logged in. If not, I set the $_SESSION['contloc'] to the url of the that page and redirect the user to the login page.

```
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    $_SESSION['contloc'] = 'sub-page.php';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

In the script where the user / password is validated, I then get the value of $_SESSION['contloc'] and redirectx the user to the page the user initially opened:

```
$continueLocation = '';
if(isset($_SESSION["contloc"])&& !($_SESSION["contloc"] === "")){
   $continueLocation = $_SESSION["contloc"];
   $_SESSION["contloc"] = '';      //reset continue location
   header('Location: ' . $continueLocation);
   exit;
}else{
   header('Location: menu.php');
}
```

(if the user did not come from a sub-page, the authenticate script simply redirects to the menu.php)