# Using PHP, how do I determine which page I came from?

Tags: php

First off, I am a PHP noob.  That said, I have some PHP code that was given to me which creates a PayPal shopping cart.  One of the buttons (Continue Shopping) on the Cart page is supposed to return to the previous Product page (of which there are several such pages) which has the View Cart button.

How do I determine which Product page to return to? Put the page name (i.e. "productList1.html") in a hidden field?

Regarding possible duplicate: I saw that page, and this comment on that page "The problem with this is that HTTP_REFERER is unreliable at best.", so I decided to ask again since that was asked in 2009, and maybe things have changed since then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Returning a user to their original page after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984573/php-returning-a-user-to-their-original-page-after-login)

Comment: echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Hi there. We try to discourage voting commentary in posts, since it is not relevant to future readers. Whilst it's usually not worth adding, if you really want to ask about downvotes, this is best placed in comments. If you can keep questions/answers focussed on the topic at hand, that is best. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer: thanks, I'll do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php:

```
/* print the page from you came */
print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

But if come from your own page, you can modify the link adding a GET parameter such as `?product_id=123` at the end of link and then in your php:

```
/* print the product id */
print $_GET['product_id'];
```

Comment: just dont expect it to be reliable. its browser set, and striped for security by many a firewall

Comment: well, i'm add a get parameter solution, it's better

Comment: Given that it might not be reliable, what about using a hidden field containing the URL, which gets read by the Cart page anyway?

Comment: much better approach, or add the page to a session

Comment: @spokane-dude adding a get parameter it's a good solution for non confidential data and you set all the parameters that you need buy.php?product_id=123&currency=dollar&anything=value