# how can i successfully redirect user to where he was(his current page) after he logged in in php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to redirect user to his current page(where he was before logged in) but still it is not working. I tried with my script below; but instead of taking the user to where he was..the user is taken to the home page. Can somebody subject the right way to do it?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
 } 

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && filter_var($_SESSION['user_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,array('min_range' => 1)) ) { 
header('Location:accueil.html.php');  
}
if (array_key_exists('login', $_POST)) {

$email=$pass="";

 $errors = array();

// Check for an email address:
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
 } else {
   $errorEmail ="Entrer un email valide";
    }

if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
 $errorPass = "Entrer votre mot de passe";
} 
  else{
    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
  }

if ( $email && $pass) { //All IS GUD

include('includes/connect.inc.php'); 
 try {
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM registered_user WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);   
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':pass', SHA1($pass));
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($row) { //email and pwd combination is rigth
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    header('Location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
  } 
    else{
    $errors[] = "Nom d'utilisateur et/ou mot de passe incorrect(s)";
    }

 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $systemErr = "Désolé, Erreur de system".$e->getMessage();
 }

} else{
    $errors[] = "Désolé, votre connexion a échoué";
}

}//END MAIN IF

?>
```

Comment: You need to debug at before `header('Location:accueil.html.php');` line and `header('Location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` line. Check these two line has correct debug OR not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Returning a user to their original page after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984573/php-returning-a-user-to-their-original-page-after-login)

Answer (score 1):

You can take one session variable in each page.

See below

1) If you have header.php common file then you can add this line to store last url in header.php otherwise you can add in each page.

```
$_SESSION['last_url'] = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

2) Then you can redirect user to that url when he logged in.

```
if ($row) { //email and pwd combination is rigth
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    header('Location:'. $_SESSION['last_url']);
    exit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$usr_header = "Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header($usr_header );
exit();
```